# UploadFile doesn´t work

Tags: dropnet

Hi we are using "dropnet" API and works fine until today, just is not working the UploadFile method, play media, move or delete works fine, but the upload is not working can someone help to figuredout why?

basically the process upload the file and returns no error, but the file (.mp3 files) is not uploaded into my dropbox account as had been doing until last Friday. We tried to move or delete a file, also play the mp3 from my web page and it works perfect! How can we try to catch the error?

we use this code:

```
var fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
DropNet.Models.MetaData uploaded = new DropNet.Models.MetaData();
uploaded = _client.UploadFile("/CRM_Proximitas/" + portal + "/" +     Request.QueryString["idReclamo"].ToString() + "/" + fecha, hidTipo.Value.ToString() + hidID.Value.ToString() + "_" + fecha + "_" + usuario + "." + uplArchivo.FileName.ToLower().Split('.')[1], uplArchivo.FileBytes);
if (uploaded != null)
{
     if (hidTipo.Value.ToString() == "R")
    {
        objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ReclamoAudio (idReclamo,path,Autor,Fecha) VALUES (" + Request.QueryString["idReclamo"].ToString() + ",'" + uploaded.Path.ToString() + "'," + Session["UserID"].ToString() + ",getdate())";
}
else if (hidTipo.Value.ToString() == "T")
{
    objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ReclamoAudio (idReclamo,idTransaccion,path,Autor,Fecha) VALUES (" + Request.QueryString["idReclamo"].ToString() + "," + hidID.Value.ToString() + ",'" + uploaded.Path.ToString() + "'," + Session["UserID"].ToString() + ",getdate())";
}
objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
objCon.Open();
drContacto = objCommand.ExecuteReader();

objCon.Close();
string codigo = "window.opener.location.reload();self.close();";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FinalizarCarga", codigo, true);
}
```

We have a website with IIS 7 + Framework 2.0, also the Dropbox App now is in Development Status, this can we cause an issue?

Please I need your help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ni Mark, basically the process upload the file and returns no error, but the file (.mp3 files) is not uploaded into my dropbox account as had been doing until last Friday. We tried to move or delete a file, also play the mp3 from my web page and it works perfect! How can we try to catch the error?

Comment: I already edit the question to add more info.

Comment: Dear all, magically today start working again! without any changes.